# Add properties in an entity in the Service Layer?

Tags: service-layer, sapb1

How can I update the service layer to have new properties inside an entity that I created in SAP B1 9.3.

I have a created ServiceLayer - SAP B1.

Inside the table OTSH I created 2 new fields, but my service Layer didn't return me that fields.

I already updated the ServiceLayer and no changes were made.

Someone can help me?!

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer.

UDF's are only exposed to the Service Layer after SAP Business One 9.3 PL11 version for SAP HANA.

My version is inferior.

Links with info:

- https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2777696
- https://answers.sap.com/questions/13280238/sap-b1-service-layer-2.html?childToView=13239891#answer-13239891